# Не пойму как исправить ошибку со split

Tags: python, telebot, типы, split

У нас есть сообщение, которое прислал пользователь

```
message = 'Сав Сем Алекс 20.11'
ms = message.text.split()
        for i in ms:

            print("i: ", i)
            print("i.split("-"): ", i.split("-"))
```

**Выдает такую ошибку:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: print('i.split("-"): ', ... Кавычки разные надо или маскировать внутри текста \"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка тут не со split, а с кавычками.

```
print("i.split("-"): ", i.split("-"))
      ^1       ^2^3  ^4
```

Первая кавычка открывает строку, вторая закрывает. Потом идет минус и еще одна строка. Именно так эту запись интепретирует питон. Откуда ему знать, что минус в кавычках это часть строки? Нужно или экранировать кавычки внутри строки или использовать одинарные:

```
print("i.split(\"-\"): ", i.split("-"))
print('i.split("-"): ', i.split("-"))
```

можно и наоборот

```
print("i.split('-'): ", i.split("-"))
```

Кстати, по подсветке кода видно, где начинается строка в кавычках и где она заканчивается. Не зря код подсвечивается разными цветами.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться возможностями f-строк `print(f'{i.split("-")=}')`

Comment: Спасмбо большое, глупая ошибка, буду внимательней)